# Why does this come up with a syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

This is my code (of which IDLE highlights 'print' and says 'Invalid Syntax':

```
import random
initial_val = 10
attributes = str("Character 1's Strength: ",(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) +         initial_val), \
"\nCharacter 1's Skill: ",(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) + initial_val), \
"\n\nCharacter 2's Strength: ",(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) + initial_val), \
"\nCharacter 2's Skill: ",(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) + initial_val)
print(attributes)
file = open("Attribute.txt", "w")
file.write(attributes)
file.close()
input("\n\nPress enter to exit")
```

Why does it do this? It's probably extremely obvious, but I'm new to programming.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The *preceding* line is missing a closing `)` parenthesis:

```
attributes = str("Character 1's Strength: ",(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) +         initial_val), \
"\nCharacter 1's Skill: ",(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) + initial_val), \
"\n\nCharacter 2's Strength: ",(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) + initial_val), \
"\nCharacter 2's Skill: ",(random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4) + initial_val)
```

The `str(` function call was never closed.

Use string formatting and `"""` triple-quoted string instead for a far more readable declaration:

```
attributes = """\
Character 1's Strength: {}
Character 1's Skill: {}

Character 2's Strength: {}
Character 2's Skill: {}
""".format(
    random.randint(1, 12) / random.randint(1, 4) + initial_val,
    random.randint(1, 12) / random.randint(1, 4) + initial_val,
    random.randint(1, 12) / random.randint(1, 4) + initial_val,
    random.randint(1, 12) / random.randint(1, 4) + initial_val)
```